# Wordpress and Bootstrap media query background image

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, media

I have a website which uses the following code to show one of two background images depending on what page of the site you are in. Media queries/responsiveness is handled by Twitter bootstrap.

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php if( is_front_page() ) : ?>
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/background-home.jpg" class="bg">
<?php else : ?>
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/background-main.jpg" class="bg">
<?php endif;?>
```

This works great - but now i need to introduce a 3rd background image (a smaller one) for mobile use.

If I target the new mobile background image in css like this...

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
body {
background-image: url('images/mobile-background.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
}
```

...it doesn't work.

Any ideas on how I can modify the header code to make sure this mobile background repalces all others on mobile only?

Answer (score 1):

Look, your code output HTML like:

```
<body class="classname">
   <img src="path" class="bg">
```

I can suggest that CSS of image with class "bg" has got an absolute positioning. This means that the image overrides a body background.

To resolve this I see a 2 quick fixes:

1) Set up a `<body>` tag with corresponding class names for "front_page" and "default_page" (you may use if-else that already written or any other way) that will takes `background-image: url('img/background-home.jpg');` and `background-image: url('img/background-main.jpg');` as background respectively, while mobile css should looks like:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
body {
background-image: url('images/mobile-background.jpg') !important;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
}
```

2) You can use https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect to set up a function to detect mobile devices:

```
function isMobileDevice() {

    $oMobileDetect = new Mobile_Detect();

    if ($oMobileDetect->isMobile()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and call it in if-else before is_front_page() for your mobile background in a way you did for background-home and background-main images.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I should have clarified I am using a full-screen resizable background reliant on javascript for resizing. That is why it is called in a DIV and not as a true BODY background.
Do you have any suggestions in light of this as to how I can call a mobile-only image in that same BG class DIV?

Comment: You can use any kind of selector in @media section. Due to a lack of JS code I can't tell you if it will works (JS can put in-line styles, that has a priority even on !important), but please try this:<code>@media (max-width: 480px) {
.any-class-you-like{
background-image: url('images/mobile-background.jpg') !important;
}}</code>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CSS and media queries to manage the background image, make sure you have the following to the head of your page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

If you are using WordPress, go to /wp-content/themes/your-theme/header.php and add the above before the closing  tag if it isn't already present.

To clarify, the php code you quote is inserting one of two jpegs as an inline image, it isn't changing a background image.

Good luck!

**EDIT**

Your basic media query also needs a closing curly bracket:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
body {
background-image: url('images/mobile-background.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
}
}  /* new */
```

Comment: That is already in my header. Any ideas as to how address my problem? I understand the use of media queries and these are working fone with their assigned breakpoints. Just can't get a chosen image to show on mobiles only.